# Remote Debugging Visual Studio Code, Django, Daphne, Daphne Workers running in Docker Containers

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, daphne

Just started using visual studio code for python development and I like it so far. I am having issues doing remote debugging in a django app running on docker. Was hoping someone would point me in the right direction to setup V.S debugging in django through docker.

I am running Django rest framework in docker container. I am using asgi server daphne because of websocket connections. I want to know if there is a way to use remote debugging in django running in docker with daphne workers.

I have looked at some [tutorial](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/debugging-django-project-in-docker/) but they are for wsgi part. The problem I am having is that daphne uses workers to connect to daphne server and process the requests that way.

Things I have tried:

- Able to use `pdb` to debug. Have to connect to the worker container and also specify `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true`. It works but is a tedious process.
- Tried the steps involved in the tutorial URL specified but it didn't work for Visual Studio Code.
- Also tried using remote debugging in pycharm but the background skeleton processes make my computer really slow. But I was able to make it work. Hoping I could do the same in Visual Studio Code.

Here is my daphne and daphne worker settings for  docker-compose.yml

```
  #-- Daphne Webserver
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: web
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 datuhweb.asgi:channel_layer --access-log=logs/daphne.access.log
    environment:
      - ENV: 'LOCAL'
    expose:
      - "8001"
    volumes:
      - .:/app


  #-- Daphne worker
  daphne_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: daphne_worker
    environment:
      - ENV: 'LOCAL'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: python -u manage.py runworker -v2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

I am getting a connection error.
Here is my setting for visual studio code

```
{
        "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "/app/",
        "remoteRoot": "/app/",
        "port": 3500,
        "secret": "my_secret",
        "host": "172.18.0.8"
    }
```

This gives me a connection error.

Comment: Found this resource, couldn't get it to work. Using just PDB for now. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: Have you tried the [VSCode instructions for remote debugging of dockerized Python apps when using docker-compose](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose#_python) already?

Comment: I've not tried this miself but use [pdbpp](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/) instead as well btw...